# Autolayout - stretching a view to fill its parent view

Tags: ios, objective-c, autolayout

I noticed some very strange behavior when trying to fill a view with a child view using autolayout. The idea is very simple: add a subview to a view and make it use all of the width of the parent view.

```
NSDictionary *views = @{
                        @"subview":subView,
                        @"parent":self
                       };
```

This does not work:

```
[self addConstraints:
      [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|[subview]|" 
                                              options:0 
                                              metrics:nil 
                                                views:views]];
```

The subview doesn't use the full width of the parent view.

But this works:

```
[self addConstraints:
      [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|[subview(==parent)]|" 
                                              options:0 
                                              metrics:nil 
                                                views:views]];
```

I would expect that both would work as intended. So why is the first example not working? It is what Apple recommends in the following technical note:

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/technotes/tn2154/_index.html

**EDIT**: (removed irrelevant information)

Comment: It works when I do it. What result do you see? Are you getting any warnings in the console?

Comment: No autolayout warnings. The subview is only as wide as the widest element in it, not taking up all of the space in the parent view. When I sue the 2nd example it works fine (it then uses all of the parent view's width)

Comment: You need to provide more information. What views do you have inside subview, and what constraints do you have setup on them?

Comment: It's a very complex view with a lot of internal constraints. But my question is: aren't both my code examples supposed to do exactly the same? Why do they behave differently?

Comment: They should be the same, so without seeing what you've done, it's impossible to say why you get that result. Can you create a simpler setup that reproduces this result, and fully describe it or post it somewhere?

Comment: The two would **not** be equivalent if `parent`/`self` is not actually the superview of `subView`. Are you sure it is?

Comment: @KenThomases Yes, I am absolutely sure because the line immediately preceding the above code is `[self addSubview:subView]`.

Comment: Add the method [in this gist](https://gist.github.com/mayoff/85f6d7b41b6584deff94) to your parent's view class.  Run your program.  Copy all the output from the debug console and paste it into your question.

Comment: You didn't post the recursive description part for the two cases. That might be useful. If you do post it, be sure to update the constraint logging, too, so they go together in terms of view addresses. There are some views which are still using autoresizing masks. Not clear if it's part of the problem. You seem to have over-specified parts of the layout, meaning they have no flexibility to adapt to different widths. `WeatherTypeBoxView` and `AdditionalWeatherInfoBox` are constrained to 160 points as well as their position relative to each other and their superview, forcing it to an exact size.

Comment: If you are adding your constraints programmatically you should disable the conversion of autoresizing masks into constraints, are you doing that?

Comment: Tell us, which of the many views in your constraint dump is the `subview` and which is the `parent` from your code?  Also, post screen shots of your app with the broken layout and the correct layout.

Comment: What messages appear in your debug console for the bad layout?  What messages appear for the good layout?

Comment: @rob mayoff: none. No conflicts

Comment: I've had to change the code in the meantime and the issue no longer appears, but it got me really curious about this. I will try to create a reproducable test case because I still feel that both versions of my parent-child constraint should work exactly the same (i.e. use all of the parent's width)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason this was not working as expected was this:

The parent view is a **UISCrollView**, and the horizontal constraints are set to `"H:|[contentView]|"`, the contentSize of the scrollview will adjust itself to the width requested by `contentView`, not the other way around. So the autolayout engine will first determine the dimensions of `contentView` and then adjust the contentSize of the parent (scrollview) to the same width. If `contentWidth` is narrower than the parent, it won't stretch because the contentSize of the parent (scrollview) will shrink to the size of `contentView`.

For regular views (not scrollviews), the width of the parent view is fixed so it will first layout the parent view and then the child view(s).

By forcing the width of `contentView` to the same width as the parent scrollView, `contentView` will always be the same width as the parent scrollview, which is what I wanted (and expected).

Comment: Wait, so are you saying that you were in fact seeing the parent view being shrunk to the width of the child view?

Comment: @algal Yes, that's exactly what was happening. It's very easy to reproduce in a test project. Simply add a UILabel to a UIScrollView with the constraints `H:|[label]|` and the content size of the scrollview will shrink to the size of the label.

Comment: Okay. So I wasn't as completely wrong as I thought. Good to know. TN2154 is still impenetrable to me, although I've read it at least 6 times now.

Answer (score 5):

Here are the constraints you posted for your “first example”:

[image: first case]

Here are the constraints you posted for your “2nd example”:

[image: second case]

I see two differences in these structures, which I have highlighted in red in the diagrams:

1. The first (broken) case has a constraint (0x8433f8f0) on the near-root `UIView` 0x8433f8f0, pinning its width to 320 points.  This is redundant, because the bottom-level views are constrained to 160 points each, and there are sufficient constraints to make all the ancestors of those narrower views be 320 points wide.
2. The second (working) case has a constraint (0x7eb4a670) pinning the width of the near-bottom `UIView` 0x7d5f3fa0 to the width of the `DetailWeatherView` 0x7d5f3270.  This constraint is redundant because 3fa0's left edge is pinned to 3270's left edge, and 3fa0's right edge is constrained to 3fa0's right edge.  I assume the `(==parent)` predicate adds this constraint.

So you might think, each case has one redundant constraint, so what?  No big deal, right?

Not quite.  In the second case, the redundant constraint is truly harmless.  You could change the width of either (or both) of `WeatherTypeBoxView` and `AdditionalWeatherInfoBox`, and you'd still get a unique solution.

In the first case, the redundant constraint is only harmless **if the width of the views doesn't change**.  If you change the 320-width constraint on f8f0 without changing the 160-width constraints on the leaf views, the constraint system has no solution.  Autolayout will break one of the constraints to solve the system, and it might well break that 320-width constraint.  And we can see that the 320-width constraint, with its `UIView-Encapsulated-Layout-Width` annotation, is imposed by the system to force this view hierarchy to conform to some container's size (maybe the screen size; maybe a container view controller's imposed size).

I don't know why your first case has this extra top-level constraint and your second doesn't.  I'm inclined to believe you changed something else that caused this difference, but autolayout is mysterious enough that I'm not 100% convinced of that either.

If your goal is to make this view hierarchy fill its container, and keep the leaf views equal width, then get rid of the 160-width constraints on the leaf views and create a single equal-width constraint between them.

Comment: As mentioned in a comment on algal's answer, I suspect the `UIView-Encapsulated-Layout-Width` constraint is present in both cases. Keep in mind that `-constraintsAffectingLayoutForAxis:` doesn't return all constraints on the view, it only returns the ones which affect the layout. In the case of a redundant constraint, I guess it's arbitrary whether it's included or not.

Comment: I saw your comment, but since we're looking for a culprit, and that constraint could certainly cause layout problems, I'm treating it as a suspect for now.

Comment: Are you sure that autolayout will break one of the constraints if there are redundant (but compatible) constraints? I know that if one of the constraints contradicts another, one of the 2 will be dropped, but is this also the case for non-contradicting constraints? If so, that could explain a lot.

Comment: It only breaks constraints if the system cannot be satisfied.  If you have multiple, redundant constraints, but there is a solution, then it doesn't break any constraints.

Comment: I found the issue, and I will post the conclusion here later (I don't have time right now). It's related to the special way UIKit handles views embedded in a scrollview. Your explanation helped a lot in helping me understand where to start looking.

Comment: @robmayoff Please tell me there's some other way the rest of us mere mortals can generate that awesome constraint diagram?? :)

Comment: @PhilippeLeybaert We await with bated breath!

Comment: @algal I drew it by hand with OmniGraffle.

Comment: @robmayoff that's cheating. :)

Answer (score 2):

EDIT: as Ken Thomases has pointed out, I'm completely wrong here!

Yes, both of the constraint systems you specify should cause the `parent` and `subview` (or `parent` and `contentView`) to have the same width.

So I would ask, are you absolutely sure that what you're seeing is the `contentView` fail to fill the parent? Is it possible what you're seeing in the broken case is that the parent is actually being shrunk to fit the contentView, and you're not noticing it because the parent has a transparent or otherwise invisible background?

To check this, set the `contentView` and the `parent` to have different opaque background colors. If I am wrong, you will clearly see a region of background where the parent extends out with a width greater than the contentView. If I am right, the contentView will completely cover the parent's width.

Here is why I am (maybe presumptuously) questioning your stated fact about what you are seeing:

The key difference in your log outputs are that, for the broken case, we see an unexpected constraint that holds a UIView to a *fixed width* of 320:

```
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x8433f8f0 'UIView-Encapsulated-Layout-Width' H:[UIView:0x841b9f40(320)]>
```

What view is that? Based on the constraint name "UIView-Encapsulated-Layout-Width", that it is associated with a `UIViewControllerWrapperView`, and that the width is being held to 320 (width of an iPhone), we can deduce this constraint is automatically created by UIKit to constrain the size of a UICollectionView.view to the size of the screen. Looking at all the constraints, you can further see that this width=320 constraint is passed down via a chain of constraints (encapsulated-view -> DetailView -> DetailWeatherView) until it ultimately determines the width of `DetalWeatherView`, which is your `parent`, and which uses superview-edge-offset constraints to hug the `contentView`, which should therefore also get that same width of 320.

In contrast, for the case that works, you can also see the same chain of constraints that should constraint the `contentView.width` to equal the width of the top encapsulated layout view. But the difference is there is no constraint anywhere that holds anything to a fixed value of 320. Instead, there is only a left-alignment constraint.

So I would expect to see that in both cases `contentView.width == parent.width`, but that in the broken case width=320 whereas in the working case the width is being determined by lower-priority internal constraints within `contentView` that allow it to expand to a value greater than 320, perhaps to its intrinsicContentSize.

Comment: You're incorrect about there not being anything that constrains to 320 width in the second case. The `WeatherTypeBoxView` and `AdditionalWeatherInfoBox` are both constrained to 160 width and adjacent to each other and the mutual superview's edges. So, that fixes the hierarchy at 320 width, too. I'm not sure how much we can make of the "extra" constraint showing up. I think that constraint exists in both cases, it's just that it's redundant. The layout system may not consider redundant constraints to "affect the layout" in the sense of `-constraintsAffectingLayoutForAxis:`.